# Networking multiple computers to one brain in Java

Tags: java, networking

I was wondering which libraries or API's would be useful in this. what im aiming for is to be able to type a command into a prompt and then specify which computer(out of all of them that are networked together) to execute that command on. the second part is i want to be able to see that command execute and the result on the computer that was specified.

for example if i enter "firefox www.google.com, desktop2" i want to be able to see the window open on the monitor of that computer. Do you understand what im trying to do? any help is appreciated.

Thanks, Morpheous

Comment: *"Do you understand what im trying to do?"* - I think so, but I don't understand why you think it is a sensible thing to do.  Perhaps you've been watching too many SF movies?  [ BTW - it is spelled Morpheus :-) ]

Comment: I'd question whether it's appropriate to do this programatically. Using VNC, Remote Desktop or X over SSH is far better (which OS are you targeting?) - especially where security is concerned.

Comment: I do watch alot of scifi movies, but nothing is impossible. also, i liked morpheous better, :). Um i understand that vnc is better, but i cant integrate someone elses vnc into a larger program, also i dont need it that complex.

Answer (score 1):

I think I do, but not why. For example, there are existing mechanisms for doing this. If you've got sshd running on each of your "multiple computers" you could simply, from "control", run:

```
ssh -X user@desktop2 firefox www.google.com
```

and you'd use remote X to forward firefox back to your local desktop (actually being executed on desktop2). Try `man ssh` for more information and ask on serverfault if you want to know more.

If you're looking to develop something that achieves this sort of idea, that's a different matter and I'd question if Java is the best way to do it (opinions vary but it's not a "systems language"). Again, existing solutions exist such as the build systems used for projects like Fedora (see [Koji](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Koji)).

My advice would be to research a lot of existing code and only if this doesn't solve your problem or if you want a challenge, write something new.

Comment: i realize there are exsisting ways of doing this, but im researching this in particular for a way bigger project, and this is a part of it thanks tho, i will keep ssh in mind when doing this task. :)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, PSExec will do that:

The command line is

```
Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]
              [-u user [-p psswd]][-n s][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]]
              [-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-<priority>][-a n,n,... ] 
              cmd [arguments]
```

For example:

```
psexec \\computer2 -i firefox.exe www.google.com
```

Will execute firefox interactively on the remote computer.

See
 - [PSExec, Microsoft PStools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

Comment: can psexec be combined into a larger java program? and do you know anything that does the same on linux?

Comment: I'd suggest you search elsewhere on Stack Overflow in order to see how to execute a shell command in Java (it's been answered many times). X-forwarding over SSH (i.e. Ninefingers' answer) is how you'd want to do it in Linux (ideally, with certificates instead of passwords).